# Query breaks when data contains single quote

Tags: php

Hello guys i need your help with this php code,
and trying to create survey name using text box..but what happens is that `$survey_name = $_POST['txtSurveyName'];` does not save any input with e.g. `Department's` but it saves `Departments`.

I noticed that the problem is with the single quotes, how can write this code to accept the single quotes?

here is the full code:

```
    **$survey_name = $_POST['txtSurveyName'];**
    $survey_status = $_POST['status'];

    // Save question
    $sql = "INSERT INTO survey(survey_name, status) VALUES('{$survey_name}','{$survey_status}')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    // Redirect to landing page
```

Comment: This should be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @nietonfir it's a fairly short question, if you bothered to read it you'd see it's not a code review question.

Comment: @Sammitch Agreed. It should be flagged off-topic. ;-)

Answer (score 9):

As much as I hate this answer I will still tell you that you need to escape your strings:

```
$survey_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txtSurveyName']);
```

But I would suggest using **PDO** or **MySQLi** prepared statements. Better for your security.

So easy with PDO:

```
//prepare query
$stmt = $pdoInstance->prepare('INSERT INTO survey(survey_name, status) VALUES(:name, :status)');

//bind params
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':status', $status, PDO::PARAM_STR);

if ($stmt->execute()) {
  //success
}
```

This way your code is more secure and I feel better that I did not suggest something horrible.

Comment: +1 for suggesting **PDO** and **MySQLi**!!

Comment: `$survey_name = "Bobby'; DROP TABLE users; -- ";`

Comment: +1 for showing a PDO example.

Answer (score 1):

From: https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string

```
$survey_name = $_POST['txtSurveyName'];
$survey_status = $_POST['status'];

$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO survey(survey_name, status) VALUES('%s','%s')'",
    mysql_real_escape_string($survey_name),
    mysql_real_escape_string($survey_status));

$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to escape specials chars :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO survey(survey_name, status) VALUES(\"{$survey_name}\",\"{$survey_status}\")";
```

or

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO survey(survey_name, status) VALUES('".addslashes($survey_name)."','".addslashes($survey_status)."')";
```